# UIScrollView scrollViewDidEndDragging and scrollViewDidEndDecelerating not working

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have searched and found multiple posts that the recommended way to determine when a user stopped scrolling, and when a UIScrollView stopped moving is the following:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
   // Perform desired outcome here.
   NSLog(@"scrollViewDidEndDragging");
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   // Perform desired outcome here.
   NSLog(@"scrollViewDidEndDecelerating");
}
```

I have tried multiple ways, I can not get it to work.

Is there something obvious I am missing? Something with the delegate?

Comment: The first thing you need to make sure is to set the delegate for your UIScrollView..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you have all the following code inside your ViewController.

Under your **ViewController.m** add

```
@interface ScrollViewTestViewController ()<UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Inside **ViewDidLoad**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.scrollView1.delegate=self;
self.scrollView2.delegate=self;
}


-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
                         willDecelerate (BOOL)decelerate {
 // Perform desired outcome here.
 NSLog(@"scrollViewDidEndDragging");

 if(scrollView==self.scrollView1)
   //Do Something
 else if(scrollView==self.scrollView2)
   // Do Another thing
 }
```

Add a **Screen Shot** and a **content size** to simulate the scrolling behaviour.

[image]

Comment: I went ahead and typed everything out again. I get an error:

"USE of undeclared identifier 'scrollViewDidEndDragging"
and
"Use of undeclared identifier 'scrollViewDidEndDecelerating"

Comment: Ok I got it working. My next question is how to I get this to work on 2 or more UIScrollViews in the same viewcontroller?  You cant have 2 self.delegates. It works for one named scrollView, but what about scrollView2 and scrollView3? Thanks.

Comment: You can have as many scrollviews as you want inside the same viewcontrollers but inside the delegate methods of the scrollview, you will have to do use if-else statement to differentiate the different scrollviews. I have just updated a sample code above.

Comment: Oh wow, that was a lot simpler that I was thinking. I was thinking much more complicated that that. Thank you very much Ricky!

Comment: No problem, Eric. I am glad that I can help. ;)